# What are possible sets for these castle pieces?

Tags: set-identification

I bought what I thought was a box of Lego bricks that contained a castle. About half the castle pieces were there. This is a picture of some of the major and larger pieces. I'm wondering if someone can help me identify some sets these may belong to.

[image]

Comment: The wheel looks like <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4790b&in=S> 4790b: Boat, Ship's Wheel with Slotted Pin but there don't seem to be any sets with 3 or more. Same with the non-slotted variant 4790.

Comment: The part on the bottom left looks like <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98280&in=S> 98280 which doesn't seem to be in any castle set in that color.

Comment: Do all the possible studs say LEGO on them? In particular, I don't think I've ever seen a Lego piece like those brackets in the bottom left (but I don't recognize them as any clone brand piece, either).

Comment: @RSchulz it is 98287.

Comment: Oh, so it is! Sorry. Me looking for 2x4 brackets didn't help. I was able to get my hands on a Ghost long ago, but it was for someone else, so I never built it. Bricklink doesn't show it in any castle sets either: <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98287&in=S>

Answer (score 9):

The parts on the bottom left of your picture are 98287 "Bracket 3x4 3x4", which [appear in a very limited number of sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98287&in=S). Of those, I think you have bits and pieces of [4204-1 "The Mine"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4204-1):

[image: 4204-1 The Mine]

Note [30293](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30293&idColor=85)+[30294](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30294&idColor=85) boulders, [6108 arch 1x12x3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6108&idColor=86), [98280 panel 1x6x3 with studs on sides](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98280&idColor=86) and [30150 crate 3x4x1⅔](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30150&idColor=88) all appear in that set too.

---

You seem to have exactly 12 of [90195 Window 1x2x2 castle, in tan colour](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=90195#T=C&C=2). That narrows down the search quite a lot, down to [8639-1 Big Bentley Bust Out](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8639-1):

[image: Big Bentley Bust Out]

That's also the only set to feature [2454pb062 "Brick 1x2x5 with Electricity Danger Sign Pattern (Sticker)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2454pb062), which is only barely visible in the above picture:

[image: 1x2x5 brick with sticker]

The [parts list for that set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8639-1) also lists [6233 Cone 2x3x2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6233&idColor=85) and [60208 wheel 31mm D. x 15mm](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60208&idColor=85) in dark bluish gray.

That set does **not** cover the 8x8 tan plate, though.

---

Your brown parts (in particular, the reddish brown [4790b rudder wheel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4790b&idColor=88)) suggest that you have parts of *several* pirate boat sets.

My *wild guess* is [70413-1 The Brick Bounty](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70413-1), but just because the parts list for it also includes a [64951 barrel half large AKA "crow's nest"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64951&idColor=88) and a [30150 crate 3x4x1⅔](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30150&idColor=88). I could be wrong, though.

---

The two technic-looking parts at the very right of your photograph seem to be "Projectile Cannon", either 57029c01 or 57029c02. [There is a limited number of sets with two such parts](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57029c01&in=S), but I cannot give a good guess.

---

For the rest of the parts, I have no good guesses.